# Ada: Subtype Conversion or calling 'Base

Tags: types, operator-overloading, ada

I have the following -simple- problem: A delta-type for representation of degrees and a subtype of it, angles, where I limted the range from 0.0 .. <360.0.
Now, I want to override the "+"-operator for the subtype to have my own modulo-operator:

```ada
package ...
type Degree is digits Degree_Digits;
end package

package ...
subtype Limited_Angle is Degree range Degree_Min .. Degree_Max;
function "+" (Left, Right : in Limited_Angle) return Limited_Angle;
end package
```

And the implementation:

```ada
function "+" (Left, Right : in Limited_Angle) return Limited_Angle is
    res : Degree;
begin
    res := Units.Base.Degrees."+"(Left, Right);
    ...
    return Limited_Angle(res);
end "+";
```

But I do not like the way, the +-operator is called. My first idea was to have something like

```ada
res := Degree(Left) + Degree(Right);
```

But this does not work. My compiler is warning about infinite recursion.
Even the more strict:

```ada
res := (Degree(Left)) + (Degree(Right));
```

is warning about infinite recursion. And I do not understand the principle behind this. Shouldn't T(S) transform S to T? It can't be an optimization problem since (T(S)) does also not work.

Did I miss-understand the concept of type-subtype conversion (most probably) and does anyone have a solution/explanation? Or even a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to type conversion, but to understanding the difference between types and subtypes.

All subtypes of a type have exactly the same operations.  The differences between subtypes of a type (including the type itself, technically the "first subtype of the type") is only the set of allowed values.

This means that all your conversions between `Degrees` and `Limited_Degrees` don't do much, and your call to `Units.Base.Degrees."+" (Left, Right)` is actually a recursive call.

I think the solution to your problem is to make `Limited_Degrees` a derived type, and not a subtype.

Answer (score 0):

No Compiler available right now, so this isn't tested, but

```
res := Units.Base.Degrees."+"(Left, Right);
```

is suspicious as you shouldn't need to specify the operator `"+"` for `left` & `right`, which are `Limited_Angle`. so I wonder if the above line is calling the current `"+"` operator (And therefore recursive)?

I would see if writing :

```
function "+" (Left, Right : in Degree) return Limited_Angle
```

Is a better option as you can do your `"+"` math in `Degree` before modulo(ing) to `Limited_Angle`. This will also save your casts on call.